# How to get return value as #t and #f from a recursive call in Scheme?

Tags: scheme

This is working code call +/- calculation which returns `(calculate '(3 2 1) 0 0) -> 0` and `(calculate '(7 5 1 2) 0 0) -> 1`.

I would like to achieve **#f** or **#t** as a result. Thank you in advance.

```
(define calculate(lambda (List sum1 sum2)
                   (cond ((null? List)(if (> sum1 sum2) (- sum1 sum2) (- sum2 sum1)))
                     ((> (calculate (cdr List) (+ sum1 (car List)) sum2)(calculate (cdr List) sum1 (+ sum2 (car List))))
                          (calculate (cdr List) sum1 (+ sum2 (car List))))
                     (else (calculate (cdr List) (+ sum1 (car List)) sum2)))))
```

Answer (score 1):

There is no hint what values you would want it to evaluate to `#t` or `#f` but the essence would be to make your `calculate` a helper and do the logic by analyzing the result:

```scm
(define (calculate lst sum1 sum2)
  (define (calculate lst sum1 sum2)
    ...) ; original implementation

  (let ((result (calculate lst sum1 sum2)))
    (if (zero? result) 
        #f
        #t)))
```

Comment: Thanks Morales:  
(cond ((null? list) 0)

If we have initial value for list is zero then we can have positive and negative return value. So I wanted to get #t for positive (true) and #f for negative (false) using condition in lambda function.